# VBA code does not trigger at all if the code contains errors

Tags: ms-access

I'm currently working on building a client database in MS Access 2010 (Have also tried in 2003 and 2007 with the same results) however if the code contains any kind of error, instead of failing or throwing a run time error it simply does not trigger.

For instance the following should throw a runtime error about dividing by 0 but instead nothing happens, the debug is not even triggered.

```
Private sub somebutton_Click()
   debug.print ("triggered")
   dim x as integer

   x = 1 / 0
end sub
```

If I find and remove the errors then the code works just fine, but it makes for some extremely difficult debugging.

Any ideas?

Comment: Strange. I just tried it in Access 2000, and here it works as expected: first it outputs "triggered", then it crashes because of the division by zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is something abnormal in your environment which is blocking the debugger. I have found this related question [MS Access 2003 does not enter into debug mode and ignores breakpoints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1476138/ms-access-2003-does-not-enter-into-debug-mode-and-ignores-breakpoints). I found another reference which repeats this advice for Access 2007.

Comment: enabling access special keys as suggested in the linked post worked. Thanks!